# Pick out first non missing element by row

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table

Suppose I want to do the following:

1) Apply some function, which replaces not needed characters by empty spaces row by row;
2) Then it picks out (out of the original data) row by row first non empty element (according to the above transformation).

Here is what I have now:

```
library(data.table)
data<-data.table(x=c("25&&&35&&1","&&&&","&&&&"),
                 y=c("&&&&&","1","&&&&2"),
                 z=c("&&&&&","","1"))

function_select<-function(x){
  x[gsub("&","",x)!=""][1]
}

data[,function_select(unlist(.SD)),.SDcols=c("x","y"),by=1:nrow(data)]

   nrow         V1
1:    1 25&&&35&&1
2:    2          1
3:    3      &&&&2
```

I have roughly 70 millions of rows, I have two questions:
1) Is there a faster solution in using data.table;
2) Can I speed up my calculations using ideas from parLapply;

Comment: You should show expected output. The first character is selected via `substring`, not `[1]`, so maybe you want `melt(data[, r := .I][, c("r","x","y")], id="r")[value %like% "[^&]", .(variable = first(variable), char = substring(first(value), 1L, 1L)), by=r]`

Comment: @Frank thanks, I edited the question, it is the first nonempty element which I want

Comment: @akrun would that be faster ? I do not see a lot of difference between yours and main answer

Comment: @akrun I also do not understand a little bit, why do we need transpose!

Comment: I think you are right.  Perhaps this could be of help, but it is not entirely dat.table solution `j1 <- data[, do.call(pmin, c(Map('*', lapply(.SD, function(x) NA^grepl("^&+$", x)), 1:nrow(data)), na.rm=TRUE))]; as.matrix(data)[cbind(1:nrow(data), j1)]#[1] "25&&&35&&1" "1"          "&&&&2" `

Comment: Transposing makes sense because you're doing rowwise operations, which are very clumsy in R and in data.table in particular. If you transpose, then it might be possible to iterate over columns, which is less bad. Generally, I think data.table does best with by-group operations working on data in long format, like `melt(data[, r := .I], id="r")`

Comment: @akrun could you put back your solution via transpose I tried to find it but it disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

Avoid by row operations in R like the plague. Here I'd probably do:

```
data[, lapply(.SD, sub, pattern = "^&*$", replacement = ""), .SDcols = x:y][
     , as.matrix(.SD)[.SD != ""]]
#[1] "25&&&35&&1" "1"          "&&&&2"
```