# Transpose data.table, apply a function and then put the result back into data.table

Tags: r, data.table, transpose

This is somehow related to my previous question:

[Pick out first non missing element by row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41876958/pick-out-first-non-missing-element-by-row#comment70937473_41876958)

In that example I have a lot of row operations to do. Maybe somebody can suggest how to within a data.table transpose a bunch variables then apply function to them and then get it back;

I tried something like this:

```
library(data.table)
n <- 1e5
# insert set.seed here
data <-data.table(x=sample(c(round(rnorm(1),2),"FIELD_NOT_FOUND"),n,replace=TRUE),
                 y=sample(c(round(rnorm(1),2),"FIELD_NOT_FOUND"),n,replace=TRUE),
                 z=sample(c(round(rnorm(1),2),"FIELD_NOT_FOUND"),n,replace=TRUE))

function_select <- function(x){
  paste(x[gsub("&|FIELD_NOT_FOUND","",x)!=""],collapse="####")
}
```

I would like to have:

```
                x               y               z   my_new_var
1: FIELD_NOT_FOUND FIELD_NOT_FOUND             1.1          1.1
2: FIELD_NOT_FOUND FIELD_NOT_FOUND             1.1          1.1
3:            1.34 FIELD_NOT_FOUND FIELD_NOT_FOUND         1.34
4: FIELD_NOT_FOUND FIELD_NOT_FOUND             1.1          1.1
5:            1.34            0.67 FIELD_NOT_FOUND 1.34####0.67
6: FIELD_NOT_FOUND            0.67             1.1  0.67####1.1
```

I have a following solution:

```
data<-data[,my_new_var:=lapply(transpose(.SD),function_select),.SDcols=c("x","y","z")]
```

But I do not think that this solution is very fast maybe somebody can propose something better.

Comment: Maybe use `transpose()` instead of `data.table(t())`.

Comment: I tried this already but this does not really speed up anything. It seems that data.table is not very suitable for this kind of tasks.

Comment: Sure, you could say that of R generally for unusual (possibly misspecified) rowwise regex tasks like the one you're attempting here. Fyi, if you're going to ask a question about performance/speed, it's usually best to make an example that scales up as a function of `n`, the number of rows (or something similar), making it easier to test against.

Comment: Try formatting all your columns at front and `paste`ing them afterwards. Something like `tmp = lapply(data, function(x) ifelse(nzchar(gsub("&|FIELD_NOT_FOUND", "", x)), x, "")); ans = do.call(paste, c(sep = "####", tmp)); gsub("(^#+)|(#+$)", "", ans)`

Comment: @Frank, I corrected the example. It is not about R, using parLapply and sufficiently many cores I can get a speedup of 10 x as compared to data.table. It seems that there is some consensus that it is nearly impossible to do row - wise operations in data.table efficiently

Comment: @Vitalijs Also, if you're going to illustrate your desired output without really explaining it, it's necessary to use `set.seed` so we know what both the input and the output look like. Please choose some set.seed value and then show your desired output for that particular example. Tbh, if your data only consists of 8 = 2^3 combos, this should be very very fast just using `by=x:z`.